# Delete row based on id from another row in another table postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my `test.users` table, I have

```
id | email         | first_name
1  | john@site.com | John
2  | bob@site.com  | Bob
```

In my `test.questions` table, I have

```
id  | user_id | answer
10  | 1       | true
11  | 2       | false
```

I want to delete the row in `test.questions` where the `user_id` matches the `id` in `test.users` for one specific user only.

For example, if I want to delete the row with `id` 10 from `test.questions` (since that row corresponds to `john@site.com` in `test.users`), I can do

```
DELETE FROM test.questions WHERE answer = true AND user_id = 1
```

This will delete **only** the row with `id = 10` from `test.questions`, which is what I want.

The problem is that I don't want to hardcode the `id`.  I want to hardcode just the user's email in the query, and get the `id` dynamically.  Something like

```
DELETE FROM test.questions WHERE answer = true AND user_id = [the id of john@site.com from test.users, which is 1]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One method uses a subquery:

```
DELETE FROM test.questions
    WHERE answer = true AND
          user_id = (SELECT u.id
                     FROM users u
                     WHERE u.email = 'john@site.com'
                    );
```

Or you can use `USING`:

```
DELETE FROM test.questions q
    USING users u
    WHERE u.id = q.user_id AND
          u.email = 'john@site.com';
```

Comment: Both work great, thanks!  What's the difference?  Is one faster than the other?

Comment: @Farid . . . For your case, I don't think there is any difference.  The first is standard SQL syntax that works in any database.  The second is Postgres's way of allowing joins in `delete` queries.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for the explanation. One other question: is `users u` necessary in the `SELECT` query?  Or can we just do `SELECT id FROM test.users` as Shadiqur wrote above? I imagine the syntax of `users u` is more helpful if you're querying more than one table in the same query, like `users u, partners p`.

Comment: @Farid . . . You don't need the `u` in this case, but I recommend using table aliases and qualifying all column references.

Answer (score 1):

use subquery:

```
    DELETE FROM test.questions WHERE answer = true AND user_id = 
(SELECT id FROM test.users WHERE email = 'john@site.com' );
```

Comment: Works great, thanks!  This looks similar to Gordon's answer below, except you're not doing `SELECT u.id FROM users u WHERE u.email = 'john@site.com'`.  What's the difference?